# Limit problem. Do not understand how do I evaluate it.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[What do I do with it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le3wx.png)

I cannot use L'Hopital's rule to equaliate limits right now, thats what the teacher said.

Comment: Well, there is no $x$ in your expression but the limit is as $x \to \infty$... so either there's an error or it remains unchanged

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is unlikely to be helpful anyways. To see this, take the derivative of the denominator. The expression does not simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+3} - \sqrt[3]{8n^3+3}}{\sqrt[4]{n+4}-\sqrt[5]{n^5+5}} = \frac{\dfrac{\sqrt{n+3} - \sqrt[3]{8n^3+3}}n}{\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{n+4}-\sqrt[5]{n^5+5}}n}$$ and note that $$\frac{\sqrt[p]{\textrm{something}}}{n} = \sqrt[p]{\frac{\textrm{something}}{n^p}}$$

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to that. If you use the Superpolynomials (Go to part 1.2 in page 2 of the following pdf: https://gofile.io/d/neAPjM ) The degree of the Superpolynomial in the denominator is equal to the degree of the Superpolynomial in the numerator. Hence this limit is equal to $\frac{\text{leading coefficient of the numerator}}{\text{leading coefficient of the denominator}}=\frac{-2}{-1}=2$ this is much simpler than evaluating the limit with L'hopital rule.